# Extjs4 set bottom border false

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a form to which I need to set the bottom border false. But I am not being able to do it. And no idea how to do it. Can anyone please help me on this ?! Here is my code below :

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.sme.Smeform' ,{
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias : 'widget.smeform',
title: '<div style="text-align:center;">Basic Info</div>',
bodyPadding : '10 10 0 10',
bottomBorder: false,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just used a css and it works. Here is the answere below :

In my view :

```
border: false,
componentCls: 'bottom-border',
```

And in css file :

```
.bottom-border {
    border-left: 1px solid #99BBE8;
    border-right: 1px solid #99BBE8;
    border-top: 1px solid #99BBE8;
}
```

Comment: try wared's answer, it is more flexible.

Comment: I couldn't get this working with style attribute but your soluction worked

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure since it depends on the context but you should try this :

```
style: 'border-bottom: 0'
```